# Kidney transplant dataset

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm looking for raw data regarding kidney transplant or any organ transplant in order to perform a survival analysis with random  effects given by some kind of attributes such as hospital dimension/location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that some of the information you are looking for is available but not completely out there in the open. Some leads to track down:

- **Scientific Registry of Transplant Recipients**' standard analysis file (SAF): http://www.srtr.org/data_request/saf.aspx seems to be *raw* data. You can see that many of the fields you are looking at are available in the [data dictionary](http://www.srtr.org/data_request/content/datadictionary/current/default.html). It isn't 100% clear to me how you get your hands on the actual data however.
- The **US HHS Organ Procurement and Transplantation Network** has *aggregate* data on many related things including survival at  https://optn.transplant.hrsa.gov/converge/latestData/step2.asp